# Edit portlet (xhtml part) without deploy

Tags: xhtml, primefaces, liferay, edit

I have a question concerning portlet 'hot-edition'. I wish I could change some code lines in an xhtml file and see that changes when I refresh the LR 6.1 site. Im developing portlets with 6.1 version + Primefaces 3.2.

In some cases I can change something and see the changes, but when I get a faces error, is like everything is blocked and I have to re-deploy the portlet compiling and generating the war again. So, lot of time lost on this process.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Liferay IDE with eclipse for development?
If yes, then, you can add the plugin portlet project to the server and whenever you do some changes to any file within the project just right-click and say publish and your changes will be reflected.

Or else you can also configure for auto-publish if any changes happen to the projects added to the server.

Hope this helps.